# capturing text in a link (<a>) element on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

I need to capture the `text between <a> and </a> tags` and cause a pop up message.I tried to do this as follows.However,what makes it difficult is that I cannot give id's to the links since the links are dynamically generated.So I tried to give them a `class` and used `jquery` to select the element.

Then ,I am not sure how the currently clicked element can be selected using jquery.

Suppose,the links generated are as follows

```
<a href="#" class="mylinkclass"> first link </a> <br>
<a href="#" class="mylinkclass"> second link </a> <br>
<a href="#" class="mylinkclass"> third link </a> <br>
<a href="#" class="mylinkclass"> fourth link </a> <br>
```

In javascript, I am not sure how the currently clicked element can be selected using jquery. I know that `$('.mylinkclass')` would return an array of the above 4 links.How can I write the selector code?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.mylinkclass').click(function(){getLinkText();});
}

function getLinkText(){
    alert($(this).text());
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change this...

```
 $('.mylinkclass').click(function(){getLinkText();});
```

to this...

```
 $('.mylinkclass').click(getLinkText);
```

So that you're assigning the function directly as the handler. That way its `this` value will be a reference to the element clicked.

---

If there was other work to be done before calling `getLinkText`, you could either pass the element by passing `this` as an argument...

```
 $('.mylinkclass').click(function(){
     // do other work
     getLinkText(this);
 });

function getLinkText(el){

    alert($(el).text());
    return false;
}
```

Or by using `.call` or `.apply` to make `this` in the function have the same value...

```
 $('.mylinkclass').click(function(){
    // do other work
    getLinkText.apply(this, arguments);
 });

function getLinkText(){

    alert($(this).text());
    return false;
}
```

Comment: +1 for the `other work` code because in most projects we would have to do such stuff..

Comment: there seems some problem with the selection..Even `$('.mylinkclass').click(function(){
            alert('hi');
        });` does not cause the alert box..The generated links are of `class=mylinkclass`

Comment: @damon: In the question, your `$(document).ready...` is missing the `)` at the end. This will be a SyntaxError. Check if it is there in your code. And be sure to keep your browser's developer console open to look for errors.

Comment: thanks..the problem was solved by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759594/clicking-on-newly-added-links-dont-execute-javascript-function

Answer (score 1):

Your `this` reference is lost when you call it from inside an anonymous function

```
$('.mylinkclass').click(function(){
   alert($(this).text());
   return false;
});
```

or

```
$('.mylinkclass').click(getLinkText);

function getLinkText(){
//..
```

or

```
$('.mylinkclass').click(function () {
   getLinkText(this);
});

function getLinkText(that){
   alert($(that).text());
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also write it:

```
$('.mylinkclass').click(function(e)
  {
    e.preventDefault(); // we don't want to cause the page to refresh or jump to top
    alert($(this).text());
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is how you setting up/calling your getLinkText() function.

Try the following:

```
$('.mylinkclass').click(getLinkText);
```

You need to pass `getLinkText` itself as the click handler, not an anonymous function that calls `getLinkText`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the text in the link with the **text()** function **$(".mylinkclass").text($(".link").text()**