# clicking on newly added links don't execute javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

while experimenting with jquery, I created this html and javascript.

```
<body>
<div id="results">
<div class="mylinkdiv">
<a class="mylinkclass" href="#">8</a>
: This is supposed to be a toaster.
<br>
<a class="mylinkclass" href="#">14</a>
: with a toaster maybe.
<br>
<a class="mylinkclass" href="#">51</a>
: If we're really creative.
<br>

</div>
</div>
<button id="remove" type="button" > Remove</button>
<button id="add" type="button" > Add</button>

</body>
```

the javascript has a function to popup a message containing the link text.It also has a function to add some links to the div .A function named remove which removes the inner div .

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.mylinkclass').click(function(){
           getLinkText(this);
        });

    $('#remove').click(function(){
           removeContents();
        });

     $('#add').click(function(){
           addContents();
        });
});

function getLinkText(that){
    var txt = $(that).text();
    var num = parseInt(txt);
    alert('num='+num);
    return false;
}

function addContents(){
  $('#results').append('<a class="mylinkclass" href="#">70</a>  new line1 <br>');
  $('#results').append('<a class="mylinkclass" href="#">77</a> new line2<br>');
}

function removeContents(){
  $('.mylinkdiv').remove();      
}
```

When I click on the links in the original html page ( ie the 3 links ) ,the alert box pops up.

When I click the add button,it adds two new links to the  div.But,**when I click on those newly added links ,the alert does not pop up!**

I can't understand why..can someone tell me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use .on if you are using jQuery 1.7 or .delegate if you are using jQuery 1.6

```
jQuery('#results').on('click','.mylinkclass',function() {
    getLinkText(this);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mprabhat/J7YCX/2/)

Another way you can do this is you clone your existing element, [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mprabhat/sdvH9/2/)

```
var cloned = jQuery('.mylinkclass:last').clone(true);
jQuery('#results').append(cloned);
```

In the second case event listener will also be copied and you dont need to use .on or .delegate.

Answer (score 2):

You need an **[delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)** event handler, because you items are created dynamically after dom load.

```
$('#results').on('click', '.mylinkclass', function() {
    getLinkText(this);
});
```

Comment: Technically, this isn't [`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live)-style, it's [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate)-style.

Answer (score 1):

When you add a link to the DOM after loading the page the first time, the links are not bound to the jQuery event. You should use:

```
$(document).on('click', '.mylinkclass', function() {

});
```

I was using "live()" when I first ran into this problem, but you shouldn't use that because it's deprecated according to the jQuery documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it this way:

```
$ ('. mylinkclass'). live ('click', function () {
alert ('OK')
});
```